# How to check whether a sequence contains any element of another sequence in rethinkdb?

Tags: rethinkdb

I knew that "contains" will check whether a sequence contains ALL elements of another sequence.I want to know:

```
Is there any simple way to check whether a sequence contains any element of another sequence?
```

**Update:**
I don't want to check whether A contains ALL elements of B,but any ONE element of B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to check whether some seq `seq` contains all the elements of another sequence `test_seq`, I'd use `set_difference` for that:

```
test_seq.setDifference(seq).isEmpty().not()
```

If `seq` is very large (like the result of mapping over a table), you can only do this efficiently with `reduce`:

```
seq.map(function(row) {
  return test_seq.setIntersection([row])
}).reduce(function(a, b) {
  return a.setUnion(b);
}).count().eq(test_seq.count())
```

Comment: Thanks,I don't want to check whether A contains all elements of B,but whether contains any one element of B.

Comment: In that case, the equivalent would be `test_seq.setIntersection(seq).isEmpty().not()` and `seq.map(function(row) { return test_seq.contains(row); }).reduce(function(a, b) { return a.or(b); })`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [do](http://rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/do/) with [difference](http://rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/#difference).

For example you have table **MyTable** with filed **MyArray** that contains array of strings.

```
r.table("MyTable").get("my_id").do(
    function (record) {
        return record('MyArray').difference(["something1", "something2"]).count().ne(record('MyArray').count()
          )
    }
)
```

It will return `true` if field **MyArray** contains any element of ["something1", "something2"]. Otherwise - `false`